# Término de uma Thread

Tags: java, thread

Quando é feito o disparo de várias `Thread`s em um loop específico, na finalização de cada uma, a `Thread` fica em aberto necessitando de um "close" ou é finalizada automaticamente?

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
    Process ps = new Process();
    Thread thread = new Thread(ps);
    thread.start();
}
```

O código acima fica só como exemplo, pois tenho uma lista de processos armazenados no Amazon AWS SQS, e necessito que cada processo encontrado seja executado em uma `Thread`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando uma `Thread` termina, ela "morre" automaticamente, não sendo necessária nenhuma ação para finalizá-la.

Answer (score 3):

Se cada mensagem dentro do **Sqs** for uma **Thread**, ela vai ser encerrada ao final do processamento, ou quando vc chamar o método *interrupt*.

Porém se o processamento for muito longo e for abrir muitas threads o ideal é usar um executor. Ele irá ajudar a controlar o *pool* de **Threads** e impedir que faça mais execuções que sua maquina suporte.

Nesse link tem um exemplo melhor explicado: https://dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-%E2%80%93-part-7